# Active Section ID CSS ONLY

Tags: html, css, colors

If I have , then I see the page section links highlighted.  However, when I have , the Active feature Doesn't respond.  I prefer keeping the section ID format.

How can I get the Active nav links to be highlighted with using the section ID format, Without using JS?  :--)

```css
nav li a.active {
  color: #4169E1 !important;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: .2rem .4rem;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  margin: .3rem 0.6rem;
}


nav .navbar-collapse.show li a.active  {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#header"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
      </li>

<section id="header">
```

Comment: How do you know what page is active?

Comment: Look at the HTML again.  It's a one page slider with #about, #contact,  etc., as the links that smooth scroll down the page.  Whenever somebody scrolls over a section, I want that section to be Highlighted in the navbar, Without needing to use JS.  :--)

Comment: To know when you reach the correct section you need js...., this is the point for my previous comment....your question is unclear...i think you need something like intersection observer.... Also show what you have tried

Comment: I'll check that out soon.  <div id="about"> runs Great Without JS.  Too bad that <section id="about"> Doesn't respond with Active Link Highlighting.  :--)